# Swift MKDirections calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler crash

Tags: ios, swift2, mkoverlay

I'm quite new to swift and was trying to show a polyline on a map.

After looking around found this code:

```
let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

    directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { [unowned self] response, error in
        guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }

        for route in unwrappedResponse.routes {
            self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)
        }
```

It works as expected but the app crashes(EXC_BAD_ACCESS) if the user navigates back before the line is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

After some research couldn't find a solution but learned a bit more about Swift and fixed the problem myself.

Don't know if it's the best or correct way to do it but worked for me. Maybe you have a better solution you would like to share?

Anyway here's the code:

```
directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { [weak self] response, error in
            guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }

            for route in unwrappedResponse.routes
            {
                if let weakRef = self
                {
                    weakRef.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)
                }
            }
        }
```

What I did was change [unowned self] to [weak self]. This way when the block is called self is an optional and I can check if it's nil.